# Compiling kernel with specified parameter

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules, kernel-parameters

You can easily change kernel parameters with `sysctl` and then make it persistent with **/etc/sysctl.d** but is there a fast way to change default kernel parameters like default **vm.swappiness = 60** at the kernel compiling stage.

I found that in the kernel source there is eg. **mm/vmscan.c** file and inside there is:

```
(...)
int vm_swappiness = 60
(...)
```

parameter but is it a proper way to modify these parameters existing in many source files and change them or is there a possibility to create some user file with all i want to change ?
and the same about modules. Do i need to edit module source file to add/change one option to my module like in **/etc/modprobe.d**:
`options modulename parameter=value`

Summarizing i want to change some kernel default parameters and some module options at compiling stage.

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding kernel parameters that are actually tuneable through sysctl settings**, I hardly see any interest in modifying these values by patching kernel source code.
You'll need to redo the work on next kernel update and if you go through patches, you'll need to ensure that your patches correctly apply : **Overkilling** for what actually will consist in no more than setting some different default value!

---

**Regarding hardcoded values that are just never exposed to userland**, it might be widely understood that there is definitely no interest  (or that there are high risks) to modify them. Not to say that you would need to get a deep understanding of the impacts on all other parameters depending on it. Is this possible ? I would say that unless you are some active contributor on related kernel source code : **no** !

---

**There is however some interest that can be found doing that for kernel tuneables that are not necessarily exposed to userland** depending on kernel's config options.
Let's take the examples of scheduler tuneables such as *sched_latency_ns* which will be exposed to userland only if CONFIG_SCHED_DEBUG is set.
Having this config setting will induce overhead.
It can then logically be seen inconsistent to wish reducing latencies and accept overheads in scheduler processing.
In this very particular sort of cases, it can then appear consistent to disable debugging code and hardcode the values, since it becomes the only possible way to alter the data.

Of course you realize that, doing things that way, you might well force values for which your kernel has not been tested and can break leaving you with just no way to debug. (with respect to the above example… you can actually obtain nasty results playing with *sched_wakeup_granularity_ns* values.)
Of course you realize that the next time you update your kernel, you'll need to redo all the work AND NECESSARILY understand the impacts of your settings in case of kernel changes, which implies a very deep knowledge of the kernel and, at least a careful reading of changelogs.

Therefore, *"is it the proper way to modify kernel parameters"* ? I'd say… **unless you actually widely tested your system with those tuneables set through the dedicated sysctl way supported by dedicated kernel debugging features before : NO ! Of course NO !** Even Linus himself would not do that.

---

Adding my personal experience on top of this, I must acknoledge that, for having followed that way regarding scheduler tuneables (with debugging code & misc statistics disabled) I just found myself with 0 data available to objectively confirm or infirm the pertinence of my fiddlings…

Comment: Thanks for dropping some lights on this.

Comment: Haha yes, A/B testing the scheduler is really difficult! For completeness, there’s a fourth category of values, settings which are made available as `CONFIG` values (sometimes if another `CONFIG` setting is enabled). Those typically fall under the “change at your own peril” type too.

Comment: Do you know is it possible to compile kernel with changed one of these defaults: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt or is it not recommended/possible too?

Comment: Of course you **can**. (even if this is definitely not adviseable) But, once again what is your point ? This is a list of kernel boot parameters that is to say parameters that are designed to be set on the boot command line with **much more** facility, flexibility and controls over the syntax & arch compatibility. Frankly, apart from reducing your boot time of an unnoticeable amount of nanoseconds… I just cannot understand. However, YES, this is possible.

Comment: i am switching from one (older) kernel to another (newer) and I don't want to change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` parameters all the time. Looking for good solution for setting specified parameters for older kernel

Comment: @EdiD : Should I understand that you don't want to change the boot command line "all the time" (perfectly fair and understandble) **but** that you are ready to patch and rebuild your kernel "all the time" ? And once more for what is about setting default values ? BTW I presume you get different entries in your boot menu, each of these can be associated with a dedicated boot command line. (vs everyone defaulting to the same)

Comment: Why rebuild "all the time" ? just when needed.